# How to know if increases in self-reported marijuana usage are real?

Tags: drugs, war-on-drugs, cannabis-legalization

Let's take Colorado for example.

Considering the prior existence of penalties for marijuana use, it is reasonable to expect that people may have been less inclined to admit their marijuana usage prior to its legalization.

Therefore, even if the data reflects an increase in self-reported marijuana usage following its legalization, we will still be unable to determine whether this increase is genuine or simply attributable to individuals feeling more comfortable disclosing their marijuana consumption.

So my question is: using self-reporting questionaires, how are we supposed to know if legalization of marijuana leads to increases in marijuana usage?

Comment: You don't and good studies will either have that in their fine print or a method of how they hope to account for that. Also more studies and asking about that. "How long have you been consuming?", "Did you ever lie about your consumption in a survey?". It won't be perfect but it can give you a hint about the numbers.

Comment: One useful concept is to recognize that part of the goal is to quantify as best you can the uncertainty. Basically no methodology is 100% certain, but that are methods that one can use to estimate the magnitude of the effects if there is one.

Comment: The other ways of counting are all problematic as well. Arrest data is affected by legalization. It becomes more present of mind and looked for by cops/investigators. Employees get less furtive and more caught at the same usage rate. There is no way to really know...

Comment: Whatever Colorado says, it’s still illegal, I wouldn’t recommend anyone answer in the affirmative.

Comment: See if local stores selling late night munchies are reporting an increase in sales

Comment: agreed with @ohwilleke. Probably impossible to know the real prevalence, but an approximation based on a sound methodology may be good enough to decide on policies to conduct. The definition of a "sound methodology" may (and should) be debated. But if meta-analyses and various well-thought-out methods converge to a given estimate, it may be reasonable to trust them to a certain extent, for example if you have to make a choice relative to public health policies.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a good question, and you should look at the methodology of the specific survey you have in mind (which hopefully should be detailed in their report) to find out how they address that and justify the validity of the study.

For example, this [interesting study](https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/pub/82-003-x/2018002/article/54908-eng.htm) of cannabis use prevalence in Canada from 1985 to 2015, examines nine national surveys and admits that:

> Nevertheless, results of this study should be interpreted in light of
> several limitations. Changes over time in respondents’ willingness to
> admit drug use, in their definition of what constitutes drug use, and
> in the perceived or real risk of legal consequences could neither be
> controlled nor detected, but could affect trends

In the methodology of the 2021 US National Survey on Drug Use and Health, they address this issue [by explaining](https://www.samhsa.gov/data/sites/default/files/reports/rpt39442/2021NSDUHMethodSummDefs100422/2021NSDUHMethodSummDefs100422.htm):

> Survey questions about topics such as substance use are considered to
> be sensitive because respondents may think the questions are intrusive
> (“none of your business”), pose risks for negative social or legal
> consequences if their answers were to become known, or require them to
> provide socially undesirable answers (Tourangeau & Yan, 2007).
>
> [...]
>
> NSDUH utilizes widely accepted methodological practices for increasing
> the accuracy of self-reports, such as encouraging privacy through
> self-administration of questions about sensitive topics—including
> audio computer-assisted self-interviewing (ACASI) for in-person data
> collection—and providing assurances that individual responses will
> remain confidential. Comparisons using these methods within NSDUH data
> (collected in person) have shown they reduce reporting bias (Gfroerer
> et al., 2002).

In addition, in academia, they may use specific methods to address this kind of bias (e.g. [social-desirability bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social-desirability_bias)), including [randomized response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomized_response) and [list experiments](https://dimewiki.worldbank.org/List_Experiments). These methods allow plausible deniability for the respondent, hence limiting bias.

The principle of these methods is to make it impossible to know if a specific respondent uses drug or not; but if you aggregate all the responses, you can still estimate general prevalence after conducting some additional calculations. As for the details of each method, you should read the previous links. Both methods can have some [issues](https://academic.oup.com/ijpor/article/33/2/255/6029620) or limitations, but may be better than asking directly a sensitive question. I mention specifically academia as using these methods, because I'm not sure that any national survey institute use these methods to estimate drug use prevalence (but happy to be corrected here).

Not all drug use surveys conducted in academia will use these "plausible deniability" methods, but here are some examples from academic papers using randomized response for estimating prevalence of cannabis/marijuana use or other drugs:

- [Application of randomized response techniques for investigating
  cannabis use by Spanish university students](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6877177/)
- [Estimation of
  illicit drug use among high school students in the Silesian
  voivodship (Poland) with the use of the randomized response
  technique](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/08898480.2021.1893009)
- [Randomized response estimates for the 12-month
  prevalence of cognitive-enhancing drug use in university students](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/23307544/)
- [Prevalence of cannabis use among young adults in Sweden comparing
  randomized response technique with a traditional survey](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/37132063/)

In addition, besides surveys, there are indirect methods for estimating prevalence, in particular when it's about drug used by a small proportion of the population or by a hard-to-reach population (e.g. heroin users). These methods include "[multiplier-benchmark](https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamapsychiatry/article-abstract/2796749)", "[capture-recapture](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0376871622004471)" (see this [UN document from 2003](https://www.unodc.org/documents/GAP/GAP%20Toolkit%20Module%202%20Final%20ENGLISH%2002-60052.pdf) for an account of these two methods), or [other methods](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/add.15111). They are all subject to criticism, like any method.

Comment: Difference in differences methods often by helpful in screening out a lot of potential confounding factors. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_in_differences Quantifying potential effect size from similar situations in the past (e.g. liquor use trends before and after prohibition was repealed) can also cabin the scale of what you might reasonable estimate the effect to be.

Comment: Another useful indirect way to measure drug use is monitoring wastewater for drug metabolites (see https://www.emcdda.europa.eu/publications/html/pods/waste-water-analysis_en) - if only willingness to report drug use (for yourself, your patient, ...) changes, the wastewater shouldn't show much change.

Comment: @MartinModrák Great idea, although only useful for community level aggregate usage as opposed to usage by a particular demographic like teens.